# woocommerce breadcrumbs in theme

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

I'm new to woocommerce, and I'm using Rosa theme for a restaurant website, that has online ordering system. I don't know why the breadcrumbs not working as it should.

In the screenshot, all subcategories are showing at the same time. 
What I need is something like
**Main Menu->sushi->nigiri**

What should I change in order to get the breadcrumb showing? I've tried some woocommerce breadcrumbs plugins, but non of them working. I wonder if it has something to do with the theme. and if it is about the theme, where can I override the code to show the breadcrumbs properly.

[image]

Comment: You should read & follow the documentation properly, or contact their support for help.

Comment: this is a question related to wordpress. why set it on-hold? It is rather a wordpress plug-in - woocommerce question than a programming question. I don't think i'm askin this question in a wrong community.

Comment: your question is theme specific & not WordPress if you could read the reason above `Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes`

Comment: sorry, i didn't leave that commet to you. I was trying to reply the guy @toscho who set my question to off-topic, which I'm not agree. I was mistakenly replied it to you. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Zhenyu Support for themes and plugins is [off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.